# Plotting realisations of an uniform distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

I have generated plots for 250 random realisations of the  positions of the Rabbits in the question:

Flopsy, a rabbit, lives in a circular field of radius 25m. We can express Flopsy’s position in terms of $x$ and $y$ co-ordinates $(x_F , y_F )$, where $(0, 0)$ is the centre of the field, the $x$ axis runs from west to east, the $y$ axis runs from south to north, and the units of measurement are metres.

Alternatively, in polar co-ordinates Flopsy’s location is $(\theta_F , r_F )$, where $\theta_F$ is the angle between the x-axis and the line from Flopsy to the origin and $r_F$ is the distance, in m, between Flopsy and the origin.

A second rabbit, Mopsy, lives in the same field. We denote her location by $(x_M, y_M)$ or, in polar co-ordinates, $(\theta_M, r_M)$.

If we observe Flopsy on repeated occasions, her locations can be regarded as
independent realisations of a random process in which $\theta_F ∼ \text {Unif}(0, 2\pi)$ and $r_F ∼ \text{Unif}(0, 25)$, and Mopsy's position is $x_M ∼ \text{Unif}(−25, 25)$ and $y_M ∼ \text{Unif}(−25, 25)$.

I get a cluster in the centre of the circle for Flopsy's positions but Mopsy's positions are uniformly distributed across the circle. I can see why Mopsy's positions are uniform around the circle but I would've expected the same for Flopsy as the polar coordinates still follow a uniform distribution, so I cannot see why the cluster is formed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you were to plot Flopsy's position on rectangular axes they would be uniformly distributed, but when you move to polar coordinates, it's as if you are wrapping the $\theta$ axis around the pole. Points closer to the original $\theta$ axis will be squeezed together and points far from the original $\theta$ axis will be more spread out.